# NoSuchSession Exception when trying to run Selenium on Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, maven, selenium, jenkins

OS:
Linux
Selenium Version:
3.1.0
Browser:
Google Chrome

Trying to run the selenium code on Jenkins gives this issue:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 21812
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 27, 2017 2:31:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 29075
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 27, 2017 2:32:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 6967
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 27, 2017 2:33:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 31312
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 27, 2017 2:34:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[ERROR] Tests run: 26, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 22, Time elapsed: 242.653 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] setUp(BrkProducts.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 62.029 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: 
no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: 'b94c902', time: '2017-02-16 12:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'xyz.com', ip: '10.4.124.176', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 0e4c67c28f18b452df9f0d3916aba043
    at BrkProducts.LoginTest.setUp(LoginTest.java:19)
```

Then, it skips all the following tests in that class. It follows with:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR] BrkProducts.ButtonTest.setUp(BrkProducts.ButtonTest)
[ERROR]   Run 1: ButtonTest.setUp:23->Methods.setup:135 » NoSuchSession no such session
  (Driv...
[INFO]   Run 2: PASS
[INFO]
```

The process becomes unstable:

```
Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SmokeTest/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-27T14:34:32-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/276M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SmokeTest/pom.xml to com.enso.automation/TestingAutomation/1.0-SNAPSHOT/TestingAutomation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

After all the research, it feels like the site actually doesn't load here. Not sure what is going on in Jenkins.

Any help here is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this error indicates a problem with either target application (e.g. chrome cannot start), or driver (cannot connect to chrome, for example due to version incompatibility). So do yu have an environment where it works? If so, what is the difference (especially version-wise)? Did it ever work on Jenkins? Do you have a proper headless setup? driver installation? etc. Too little information to actually help

Comment: for such issue, you need supply following information: 1. how did you create webDriver instance? local webDriver or remote webDriver? 2. where the browser opened when script running? on Jenkins Salve or on Jenkins Master or assigned by selenium grid or assigned by selenium server?  3. did you confirm the browser and webDriver are compatible on the browser opened machine?   script can pass on your local machine, not mean it will pass on any other machine(in most case, run by jenkins will lead to script run on another machine not your local)

Comment: @KirilS. It does work on my local which is a windows machine but not on the Jenkins which is a Linux machine. (I am trying to install Linux on a VM and test my code on it though) This is the 1st time I'm trying to set this up on Jenkins.

Comment: @yong I had the driver in my project files which I call from my code. It runs on Jenkins Slave with no selenium Grid or server setup. I will check with the versions on Jenkins and look for compatibility. Thanks for the help

Comment: if your Jenkins slave and Jenkis server are some machine, just check the chrome browser on jenkins server is compatible with your chromedriver which in your project files, from the error the chromedriver is 2.30, so what's the chrome version on Jenkins Slave?

Answer (score 0):

What's the Chrome version in your Linux server? From your comment I understood that it works in your Windows machine. You could install the same version of Chrome that there is in Windows. Anyway in this link https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads there are some info about the compatibilities. 
If you have the latest version of Chrome, you could try to use the latest version of the ChromeDriver (that now is the 2.32) instead of the 2.30